# Unable to read environment variables in xml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, configuration, dockerfile

I am unable to read Docker environment variables in xml file.

I have below docker setup.

**docker-compose.yaml** (part)

```
  spark:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: some.Dockerfile
    environment:
      - user_name=testuser
    ports:
      - 'xxxx:xxxx'
```

**some.Dockerfile:**

```
FROM some_image
COPY site.xml /opt/xxxx/xxxx/conf/
```

**site.xml** (part)

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.username</name>
        <value>"${env.user_name}"</value>
    </property>
```

when I am running `docker-compose up` I am not amble to get the proper value for `${env.user_name}`

I am expecting `testuser` but I am getting `"${env.user_name}"` inside the container. I am not able to find the mistake that I am doing to retrieve the env variable in my xml file.

Comment: Firstly, log into the container and check if the env var is there. Second, maybe this is not the issue but use user_name="testuser" instead, in your docker compose file. Finally, try deleting the double quotes in values in your xml file  <value> ${env.user_name}

Comment: Yes, I am getting the value of the environment variable in the container. Modified .yaml file with user_name="testuser" and changed the value in xml file as ${env.user_name} but still not able to get the value of env variable in xml file inside container

Comment: Try using the variable as `{$user_name}`

Comment: XML on its own is just a file format and doesn't do any sort of variable substitution.  What do you expect is interpreting that `"${...}"` string?

Comment: ok, is there a way that xml file pick the environment variable?

Comment: @AbhishekS tried {$user_name} even that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to acheive this using the below command. I am replacing the value in xml file, after xml file copied to docker container. Here's how my modified files look like.

**docker-compose.yaml (part)**

```
spark:
build: 
  context: .
  dockerfile: some.Dockerfile
  args:
    HOST_NAME=localhost
environment:
  - user_name=testuser
ports:
  - 'xxxx:xxxx'
```

**some.Dockerfile:**

```
FROM some_image
COPY site.xml /opt/xxxx/xxxx/conf/
ARG HOST_NAME
#Replacing the host_name value with build ARG value.
RUN sed -i -r "s/host_name/"${HOST_NAME}"/g" /opt/xxxx/xxxx/conf/site.xml
```

**site.xml (part)**

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.username</name>
        <value>"host_name"</value>
    </property>
```